# Как работает отладчик?

Tags: отладка

Как технически реализованы функции остановки и дальнейшего исполнения нативной программы? Как реализован просмотр стека, регистров и памяти?

В случае интерпретатора, понятно. Ему можно скомандовать "остановись", "покажи стек" потому что интерпретатор отдельная программа со своим интерфейсом. А вот при нативной отладке происходит какое-то волшебство, программа и отладчик работают на одном процессоре, но отладчик при этом управляет другой программой и видит все ее кишки. Как работает это волшебство?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В процессорах есть аппаратная поддержка отладчика. Команды останова, бит пошагового выполнения программ и прочие чудеса. Все это обычно работает на системном уровне приоритета. В старых процессорах (до 80386) бит пошагового выполнения был, а аппаратных приоритетов еще не было. Там отладчики работали в режиме пользователя. Впрочем, там и ОС работала в режиме пользователя. :-) Если конечно DOS можно назвать ОС.

UPD1:

> Пожалуйста подробней

Давно это было. Подробнее Вам надо читать описание аппаратной архитектуры процессоров. Причем поддержка отладчика теперь есть во всех более-менее уважающих себя процессорах типа ARM и прочих. В старых процессорах типа однокристаллок 51 серии от INTEL этой поддержки нет.

Когда я этим занимался, то все работали под DOS и отладчики и программа работали в реальном режиме. Тогда в системе команд процессора была однобайтовая команда программного прерывания. Если пользователь ставил точку останова в программе, то отладчик модифицировал программу пользователя, записывая в начало ассемблерной последовательности (которая реализует Сишную команду) эту самую однобайтовую команду программного прерывания. Когда (и если) программа проходила через эту точку, возникало программное прерывание, которое обрабатывал отладчик. Он останавливал программу пользователя, считывал все регистры общего назначения, и другую информацию, интересную для программиста типа содержимого стека, сегментных регистров, сегментов памяти и прочего. И всю эту информацию распихивал по окнам и останавливался. Когда пользователь снимал точку останова, то отладчик восстанавливал программу пользователя, записывая вместо этой самой однобайтовой команды прерывания старую инструкцию.

Также был так называемый Т-бит в регистре флагов процессора. Если в этот Т-бит записать единицу, то процессор вырабатывал Т-прерывание со своим отдельным вектором после выполнения каждой инструкции. Это Т-прерывание тоже обрабатывалось отладчиком и с его помощью можно было реализовать пошаговое выполнение программы. По этому прерыванию отладчик тоже собирал всю информацию о состоянии процессора и представлял эту информацию в удобном для человека виде в разных окнах.

Как сейчас сделано я точно не знаю, но думаю что тоже что-то вроде этого. За исключением того, что теперь, конечно, отладчик работает в системном режиме процессора, а программа пользователя работает в пользовательском режиме процессора.

Comment: Пожалуйста подробней

Comment: @Cerbo См. UPD1.

Comment: Еще нужно уточнить какой вычислитель/архитектуру вы описали

Comment: @Cerbo В тексте речь идет о DOS, значит это архитектура ранних процессоров из семейства х86. Но на самом деле такие же аппаратные средства поддержки отладчика были и на других процессорах. В частности на светлой памяти машине PDP-11 от компании DEC (на которой была написана первая версия Unix в далеком 1972 году) имелась и команда программного прерывания и Т-бит в регистре флагов процессора.

Comment: Если ТС спрашивает как работает отладчик, как вы думаете он много знает про DOS, PDP-11 и x86?

Comment: @Cerbo Ну а что делать? Аппаратная поддержка отладчика в процессоре это дело низкоуровневое, тут не обойтись без понимания работы процессора на низком уровне.